# Compare two strings and output result where both are equal

Tags: javascript

I have two strings, and I want to output one string where both give the same values. 
e.g.

```
var string1 = "ab?def#hij@lm";
var string2 = "abcd!f#hijkl]";

//expected output would be "abcdef#hijklm"
```

I have thought a way to do this would be to assign each character to an array, then compare each character individually but that seems inefficient, as I'm going to pass this through strings with tens of thousands of characters.

Any help is appreciated, doesn't have to be code, just to guide me in the general direction.

Comment: And what's the logic here ?

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly...your question is little confusing

Comment: to remove random "corruption" from the original string, by comparing two result strings and returning where they are the same

Comment: Well you'd need to define `random corruption` more precisely. Do you mean anything that's not in the english alphabet? And what about numbers?

Comment: Also, what if the characters at a given index are both letters (or not 'corrupt'), but *different* letters, which should 'win' and why? What happens if the arrays are not the same length?

Comment: Whatever the rule you are applying is, how would you possibly able to apply it without looping across all the characters (which you would not need to split the strings into an array of characters to do)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replace` with its callback argument:

```
string1.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, (_, i) => string2[i])
```

```js
var string1 = "ab?def#hij@lm";
var string2 = "abcd!f#hijkl]";

var res = string1.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, (_, i) => string2[i]);
    
console.log(res);
```

This will favour letters, but if both strings have different letters at the same position, the character in `string1` will get precedence. On the other hand, if both have a non-letter, the one from `string2` will be taken.

Comment: Nice use of the `offset` parameter to the replacer function.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop and check the character.

```js
var string1 = "ab?def#hij@lm",
    string2 = "abcd!f#hijkl]",
    result = '',
    i,
    letter = /[a-z]/i;

for (i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
    if (string1[i].match(letter)) {
        result += string1[i];
        continue;
    }
    if (string2[i].match(letter)) {
        result += string2[i];
        continue;
    }
    result += string1[i];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: But he wants a `#` in the output, based on whatever rule he is applying which is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var string1 = "ab?def#hij@lm",
    string2 = "abcd!f#hijkl]",
     result = [].map.call(string1,(c,i) => /[a-z]/.test(c) ? c
                                                           : /[a-z]/.test(string2[i]) ? string2[i]
                                                                                      : c)
                .join("") ;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your logic correctly, I guess you can do something like the following:

```
var string1 = "ab?def#hij@lm";
var string2 = "abcd!f#hijkl]";

var array1 = string1.split('');
var array2 = string2.split(''); 

var resultArray = [];
var output;

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
   if (array1[i] != array2[i] && array2[i].match(/[a-z]/i)) {
      array1[i] = array2[i];
   }
   resultArray.push(array1[i]);
}

output = resultArray.join();
```